# OSError at /account/reset_password/ and also OSError at /student/register/ [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: django

**The problem**

The error occurs when a user resets a password or when the user registers an account.

The user gets the error during registration after setting `email.send(fail_silently=False)`

This error occurs only in production environment, the project is working well in development environment

**Password Reset Error details**

***myapp/urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('reset_password/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name="accounts/password_reset.html"),
         name="reset_password"),

    path('reset_password_sent/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name="accounts/password_reset_sent.html"),
         name="password_reset_done"),

    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name="accounts/password_reset_form.html"),
         name="password_reset_confirm"),

    path('reset_password_complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name="accounts/password_reset_done.html"),
         name="password_reset_complete"),
]
```

***settings.py***

```
... other settings

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my email address'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my email password'
```